# Get null "onCreateView..(Bundle savedInstanceState)" in fragment my swipe view tab project

Tags: android, android-fragments

soory I am newbie, I looking to build the swipe view with tabs function in my application by following a tutorial from:

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

and i was succes made it, but when I try to combine with login sessionmanager and sqlitehandler in my first default tab view fragment, named "TopRatedFragmentActivity".my app force close..."unfortunately has stopped". and this my code:

```
public class TopRatedFragment extends Fragment {

private TextView txtName;
private TextView txtEmail;
private Button btnLogout;

private SQLiteHandler db;
private SessionManager session;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_top_rated, container, false);

    txtName = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
    txtEmail = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.email);
    btnLogout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);

    // SqLite database handler
    db = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity());

    // session manager
    session = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    if (!session.isLoggedIn()) {
        logoutUser();
    }

    // Fetching user details from sqlite
    HashMap<String, String> user = db.getUserDetails();

    String name = user.get("name");
    String email = user.get("email");

    // Displaying the user details on the screen
    txtName.setText(name);
    txtEmail.setText(email);

    // Logout button click event
    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            logoutUser();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
/**
 * Logging out the user. Will set isLoggedIn flag to false in shared
 * preferences Clears the user data from sqlite users table
 * */
private void logoutUser() {
    session.setLogin(false);

    db.deleteUsers();
    // Launching the login activity
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and this my fragment_top_rated.xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#fa6a6a" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/welcome"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/lbl_name"
                android:textSize="24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnLogout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
                android:background="@color/btn_logut_bg"
                android:text="@string/btn_logout"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

someone please help me... whats wrong from my code? debugger shows get null from onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) . but I dont know how to fix it

here, the error logcat:

```
08-13 21:55:08.204    6243-6243/id.nijushop.app.ikutan W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa6282288)
08-13 21:55:08.208    6243-6243/id.nijushop.app.ikutan E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at id.nijushop.app.ikutan.TopRatedFragment.onCreateView(TopRatedFragment.java:32)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:490)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1105)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:951)
            at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1473)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
            at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
            at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
            at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
            at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
            at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Show Logcat errors...

Comment: tq @dieter_h , i was edited my post and attch logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `onCreateView()`. You are looking up views using `getView().findViewById()` in your `onCreateView()`. That approach is not recommended and I bet your `getView()` returns null. From the documentation:

```
getView()
Get the root view for the fragment's layout (the one returned by onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)), if provided.
```

`getView()` will be non null after `onCreateView()` has returned.

No need to use `getView()` in `onCreateView()`. Do this instead:

```
txtName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.name);
txtEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.email);
btnLogout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLogout);
```